# Keras preprocessing: number of samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have been utilizing the keras preprocessing method `keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory()`

Here is my x and y train batches:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_path,
    label_mode = 'categorical', #it is used for multiclass classification. It is one hot encoded labels for each class
    validation_split = 0.2,     #percentage of dataset to be considered for validation
    subset = "training",        #this subset is used for training
    seed = 1337,                # seed is set so that same results are reproduced
    image_size = img_size,      # shape of input images
    batch_size = batch_size,    # This should match with model batch size
)

valid_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    train_path,
    label_mode ='categorical',
    validation_split = 0.2,
    subset = "validation",      #this subset is used for validation
    seed = 1337,
    image_size = img_size,
    batch_size = batch_size,
)
```

I wanted to know if there was a way to collect an equal sample size for each class?

Below you can see the number of sample images per class in the target directory:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why you want to load equal number of samples with the data generator. But if you want to compensate training imbalance, you can use class weights and keep all your dataset. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras

Comment: Hey thank you very much for replying, well my worry was that some classes contained 2000+ images and others below 250 images, and i was afraid that this imbalanced dataset would give a biased model?

Comment: Indeed, your model will be biased if trained on imbalanced data. There is a remedy for this which is assigning class weights in your model.fit() this way: `model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=5, batch_size=32, class_weight=class_weight)` with `class_weight` as a dictionary of class indices mapped to each class in the training loss function. This tells the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented class.

Comment: That was very helpful, if you post the answer i can vote it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To recap what's in comments: The problem is about an imbalanced dataset, training a model on an imbalanced dataset without any measures would result obviously in an biased model.

To tackle this, `Keras.fit()` has an argument called `class_weight`.  I quote the description given in the documentation:

> **class_weight**: Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to
> a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during
> training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more
> attention" to samples from an under-represented class.

Now to calculate your class weights, you can use this formula and calculate it manually, for each class j:

> `w_j= total_number_samples / (n_classes * n_samples_j)`

**Example:**

```
A: 50
B: 100
C: 200

wa = 350/(3*50) = 2.3
wb =  350/(3*100) = 1.16
wc =  350/(3*200) = 0.58
```

Or you can use scikit-learn:

```
#Import the function
from sklearn.utils import class_weight

# get class weights
class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',
                                             np.unique(y_train),
                                             y_train)

# use the class weights for training
model.fit(X_train, y_train, class_weight=class_weights)
```